# When I rebuild my c++ DLL (which I call from c#) into /CLR (originally native) the performance drops in half

Tags: c#, c++, dll, visual-studio-2013

When I changed the DLL build options from native to /CLR, so that I could debug across the c#/c++ boundary, my performance was cut in half.

I developed a native C++ DLL with specific high performance algorithms to solve my computational problems.  This DLL I needed to plug into a C# application developed by a business partner and it is used to replace their lower performance algorithm.  All was going great, I plugged in my DLL using static wrapper calls, the DLL algorithm was working great showing a 2x performance improvement over original algorithm, but could not debug across boundary.
I then switched the c++ DLL build settings from native to /CLR in order to be able to debug across the c#/c++ DLL boundary and my performance dropped in half.

Cannot figure out why that is the case.

c++ DLL side:

```
extern "C"
{
  __declspec(dllexport) void* NewCalc()
  {
    return (void*)new CalcCL;
  }
  __declspec(dllexport) double Calc(void* sCalc, int *Buf, int Cnt)
  {
    return ((CalcCl*)sCalc)->Calc(Buf, Cnt);
  }
}
```

c# side:

```
  [DllImport("CalcDLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
  public static extern int NewCalc();
  [DllImport("CalcDLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
  public static extern double Calc(int sCalc, int[] Buf, int Cnt);
...
  int sCalc = NewCalc();
...
  double res;
  int[] MyBuf = new int[1000];
  // <Code that fills MyBuf with target data for algorithm>
  res = Calc(sCalc, MyBuf, 1000);
```

Comment: Change the debugger type option in the project properties to "mixed" to enable debugging the native code with a C# project.  (Or pick both "native" and the appropriate "managed" if attaching to a process.)

Comment: Does it matter how well it performs during debugging if you can still get the best performance in production?

Comment: Also note that code using `/clr` will have JIT-time optimizations disabled when debugging, regardless of compiler settings (this can be controlled by a debugger setting -- default is to inhibit optimizations whenever a debugger is attached)

Comment: Is it really surprising that very specific optimized C++ code compiled to managed code would be a lot slower? I’m pretty sure Microsoft didn’t spend a lot of time trying to make the compiler produce the best code for these kinds of situations since you’d use native if needed, as you have.

Comment: Also note that you're paying both the penalty of reduced optimizations on the C++ side, and slow interop using p/invoke.  Normally when using `/clr` you write `ref class` objects that C# can use directly with no p/invoke.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the given interface there is no benefit to compiling with /clr at all.  Make the native C++ code debuggable by right-clicking your main C# project > Properties > Debug tab > tick the "Enable native code debugging" checkbox.  That enables both the managed and unmanaged debugging engines.  You cannot single-step into the native code, a breakpoint on the Calc() function is required to effect a debug engine change.  You might still favor a unit test written in native C++ if setting breakpoints is awkward.

The other thing you need to take care of is that you're building the C++ code with Debug settings enabled.  You got that now, that's why the code seems to be half as slow.  Only do a perf test with Release build settings so you're sure that the optimizer is enabled.  Best thing to do is to include the native C++ project in the C# solution so you always build the right flavor.  And you have to make sure that the correct DLL gets copied into the C# main project's build directory, usually done with a post-build event.  That copy step must be different for the Debug and Release configurations.

Note that the [DllImport] declarations are not correct.  The return type of NewCalc() must be IntPtr so it also works in 64-bit code.  Perf-testing the 64-bit build of the C++ code is something else you want to try, it can boost perf if the Calc() function uses floating point math.  Actually using /clr can be useful to make the interface better, you'll however have to learn how to write C++/CLI code and avoid building the native C++ code with /clr.

Comment: Not only `NewCalc` also in the `Calc` function the `sCalc` parameter should be `IntPtr`.

Comment: Thank you this answer was very helpful and addressed my needs for debugging of the native DLL.   Also good catch on the IntPtr.